# Mapbox {"message":"Tileset does not exist"}

Tags: javascript, mapbox

Why is this link saying : `{"message":"Tileset does not exist"}` for the given URL which was working few months before.

```
http://c.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/examples.map-9ijuk24y/6/17/27.png
```

Comment: The response has a status of 404: Not found. The address isn't (or is no longer) valid.

Answer (score 3):

The resource has been removed.